# How to get query with temp table to work in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm simply trying this query in PHP for the temp table, but it's not working in PHP.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##t1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##t1
select 'rec1' as col1 into ##t1;
select * from ##t1
```

PHP code:

```
$database = new SQL_DB;
$database->query(
  "
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##t1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##t1

  SELECT 'rec1' as col1 into ##t1;
  SELECT * FROM ##t1;
  "
);
$rows = $database->resultset();
```

SQL_DB class (simplified):

```
public function __construct(){
    //Set DSN
    $dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=' . $this->host . ';Database=' . $this->dbname;
    //Set options
    /*$options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
        PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8
    );*/
    $options = array(
      PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT => $this->TIMEOUT,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
    );
    //Create a new PDO instance
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        // $this->dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

//Prepare statement
public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

//Return result Set
public function resultset($in = "") {
  try{
    if ($in == ""){
      $this->stmt->execute();
    }
    else{
      $this->stmt->execute($in);
    }
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
      $this->error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

It works just fine in Microsost SQL Server Management Studio and all other queries I've worked with in PHP work just fine so it's not any of the connection problem.
It definitely has something to do with the temp table and '#'.

What am I missing?

Update:

It works just fine if I split the query into 2 parts:

```
$database = new SQL_DB;
$database->query(
  "
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##t1') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE ##t1
  SELECT 'rec1' as col1 into ##t1;
"
);
$database->resultset();
$database->query(
  "
  SELECT * from ##t1;
"
);
$rows = $database->resultset();
```

Comment: How do you execute this query in PHP?

Comment: with PHP PDO execute

Comment: Please show us the real code, not pseudo code. a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Edos That code is highly relevant for the question to be answered. Show that in your question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I updated the questions

Comment: Do you get any error or something?

Comment: Nope, simply empty $rows when checked

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem isn't the temp table but how PDO works for multiple result sets.
The fix is simply changing the way the result is fetched (in this case fetching the last result set):

```
public function lastresultset($in = "") {
  try{
    if ($in == ""){
      $this->stmt->execute();
    }
    else{
      $this->stmt->execute($in);
    }
    $result = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($this->stmt->nextRowset()){
      $result = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    };
    return $result;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
      $this->error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```